# Preprocess linux kernel on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, preprocessor

I'm trying to get the intermediate, preprocessed .i files from the linux source tree. I'm on a mac. I don't want to build the kernel, just generate all the intermediate files. 
Does anyone see an easy-ish way to do this? I tried building with CFLAGS=-E, but ran into typical build linux on mac problems.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have a lot better luck attempting it on a Linux system. Use a VM on your Mac if you don't have a Linux machine lying around. (But even so, it would probably require hacking a lot of Makefiles to do it.)

Comment: (e.g. `gcc -E` will not actually create any object files, so the dependency tree will be entirely unsatisfied throughout the "build".)